# C adding a structure to an array of structures with a constant value

Tags: c, arrays, structure, constants

I have an assignment where we need to take an unspecified list of numbers, display an unsorted doubly linked list, quicksort it, and display the sorted list.

Here is the main:

```
void main()
{
    int i =0;
    int c = 0;
    int *j = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int temp;
    int *k = malloc (sizeof(int));
    struct _myNode *a = malloc (sizeof(struct _myNode));
    printf("\nEnter the list to be sorted : ");
    while(1)
    {   
        scanf("%d",j);
        if (*j == 0)
        {
            free(j);
            break;      
        }
        else
        {       
            temp = *j;  
            c++;
            printf("C = %d ", c);
            a = realloc(a, c*sizeof(struct _myNode));
            if(i > 0)
            {
                struct _myNode newNode = { temp, NULL, &a[i-1] };
                a[i] = newNode;
                a[i-1].next = &a[i];
            }
            else 
            {
                struct _myNode newNode = {  temp, NULL, NULL };
                a[i] = newNode;
            }
            ++i;

        }
    }

    printf("\nUnsorted list is : ");
    for(i = 0; i < c; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i].value);


    //quickSort(a, 0, c-1);

    //printf("\nSorted array is: ");
    //for(i=0; i < c; i++)
    //  printf("%d ", a[i]);
    //printf("\n");
}
```

And here is the header

```
#ifndef NODE_H_
#define NODE_H_

struct _myNode{
    int const value;
    struct _myNode *next;
    struct _myNode *prev;
};

struct _myNode* quicksort(struct _myNode *head);

void printlist(struct _myNode *head);

#endif
```

When I try to compile, I am getting the error `assignment of read-only location ‘*(a + (sizetype)((long unsigned int)i * 24ul))’` at the `a[i]=newNode;` lines. From what I've been able to find, the error is due to the `int const value` element of the structure. That is one of the requirements of the assignment and therefore cannot be changed. How do I give the array a[i] the proper inputted values? I've tried doing 
`a[i] = { temp, NULL, NULL }`  and I just get `error: expected expression before '{' token`

Comment: You're really not making a linked list at all, but rather just an array of nodes.

Comment: `int const value;` --> `int value;`

Comment: @Michael Albers I know, it is the only way I know of to handle a potentially infinite list of numbers.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY One of the requirements of the assignment is that the struct be exactly what I have listed.

Comment: @Aerebes Then it would be beneficial to do a little research on how to implement a linked list. Your realloc approach will have problems when you can't allocate a large enough block of memory.

Comment: You're using realloc to create an array. Do a separate `malloc` on each input iteration and build the doubly linked list. Do this instead: `a = malloc(sizeof(*a)); scanf("%d",&a->value)` and it won't complain. Then, hook up to list with `next/prev`

Comment: The `int const value` means you cannot assign to the `value` member of a variable of that type (`struct _myNode` — a name which is treading on thin ice; for most practical purposes, names starting with underscores are reserved for the implementation to use, so you shouldn't).  You could initialize a regular (automatic or static or global) variable of the type, but if you're using dynamic memory allocation, you can't initialize the structure.  It's a very weird choice of notation.  If you take compiler warnings seriously (and you should), it will drive you spare — or you'll use lots of casts.

Comment: `a[i] = newNode;` --> `*(int*)&a[i].value = temp; a[i].prev = ...;  a[i].next = ...;`  but It might cause problems.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks a ton! It worked!

Comment: @Aerebes `a [i] = newNode`--> `memcpy (&(a[i], &newNode, sizeof (newNode));` looks much cleaner to me and should work the same.